# Leaking details about the user in web application

Tags: web-application, web-browser, webserver

Imagine a web application, which is used for getting [og](https://ogp.me/) Open Graph tags from url. User can submit a form, which has single [url](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_url.asp) input. Server opens the url in a headless browser, get `og:title`, `og:description` and `og:image` values and sends it to client.

I was told that if `og:image` is not cached on server, linking the image like that will leak details about the user who sees the preview.

I don't understand what details can be leaked. Can anybody explain this issue a bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a form of SSRF or CSRF (depending on how it is rendered), if it is not cached, it will need to fetch the image from the URLwhen viewed.

By setting the image URL to a URL the attacker control, they can possibly obtain the victim's source IP, referer URL and more from the request received to that URL.